# Invoking the resource of REST Web service

Tags: java, rest

I am writing a REST Web service. This is a snippet of Web service:

```
@Path("/first")
public class InitialResource
{ 
 @GET
    @Path(value="/{input}/{location}/{category}/{session}")    
    @Produces({"application/xml", "text/html"})
    public List<Message> getMessage(@PathParam("input") String input, @PathParam("location") String location, @PathParam("category") String category, @PathParam("session") String session) throws NotFoundException
    {
        if(date.recentUpdate(location) == false)// if false, the checking of category update was run later than 1 hour ago
        {
            user.dropTable(); // invokes method which checks if you need to drop any user's intermediate results table

            if(version.getVersion(location)== true) // if version of category did not change
            {
            }
            else
            {// version of category old; updates list of category for a specific country
             updateCategory.getCategoryList(id.getSiteId(location));
            }
        }
       return search.runSearch(input, location, category, session.split("\\.")[1]);
    }
}
```

If you invoke it through this URI

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/resources/first/cat/EBAY-IE/1/0.123
```

you get 404 HTTP error.

There is one more resource below.

```
 @GET
 @Produces("text/html")
 public String getMess( ) {
  return "hello";
 }
```

If you invoke the service with this URI

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/resources/first
```

you get "hello" string on the screen.
Why I can't invoke the first resource with specified path?

Comment: Try replacing  @Produces({"application/xml", "text/html"}) with "text/plain" and return "hello" and see if that is the problem.

Comment: Since you're throwing a NotFoundException, I'm assuming you are triggering that somewhere in the body of the method. Try removing the throws clause. That should give you a stack trace that might give you more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions, though the problem was elsewhere. I was getting HTTP 404 error accessing the Web service via client (browser). Using URI I just could not connect to the server. I only needed to update the port. And then I updated the path the client code (Javascript) accesses the service. The service system runs well. Thanks